# php dynamic vs manual array declaration

Tags: php, arrays

I have this situation where I could pre-define the array in this way:

```
$packages  = array(

        '0' => array(
            'name' => 'Hotel1', //pcg name
            'curr' => '$',  
            'amount' => '125',  
            'period' => 'NIGHT', //pcg duration
            'client_data' => array(

                'Name'    =>'Adrien',
                'Addr'    =>'Sample Street',
                'Payment' =>'Credit Card',
                'Nights'  =>'6',
            )   
        ),

);
```

Or

```
$packages   = array();
$packages[] = array(
            'name' => 'PREMIUM', //pcg name
            'curr' => '$',  
            'amount' => '3.95', 
            'period' => 'MONTH', //pcg duration
            'features' => array(

                'Clients'  =>'100',
                'Invoices' =>'300 <small>MONTH</small>',
                'Products' =>'30',
                'Staff'    =>'1',
            )   
        );
```

The data will be static always so I wont be fetching this from
a sql query or a dynamic search. Would it make any difference
in terms of performance (the slightest difference could be helpful)

by using the first or the second "method" or they're actually 100%
identical in terms of performance.

`Theorically` the "dynamic" array creation might be slower because
it needs to check the size of the array, the last array index and
maybe other things such as those.

Thank you.

Comment: The array will contain 3 sub arrays  at most.

Comment: this question will most likely be closed. however, the performance gains found in any example like that would be so small it would not make a difference.

Comment: whatever performance difference there is between the two is basically zero. both produce an array, and any minor differences in internal execution paths are going to be basically zero for anything other than a google/facebook-sized operation. In other words, you're worried about saving time on a 2 weeks vacation based on how quickly you open the car door, v.s. how fast you drive the 2000 miles.

Comment: the answer is "NO", there is no remarkable  performance difference actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple task like that takes absolutely no resources in current hardware reality. Even in my first PC, a 386DX 20MHz it would not make that difference ;)

Anyway, I executed 1k times both options:

FIRST OPTION average:

```
0.000114s
```

SECOND OPTION average:

```
0.000108s
```

Be happy!

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. So the "dynamic" method is faster?